Obtaining aggregate rotation and translation of 2D vector field (2d matrix of 2D motion vectors) produced from optical flow
I have the result of a dense optical flow in the form of 2D matrix of 2D motion vectors.
I need to isolate the rotation and translation components of the motion to estimate camera rotation and translation (for the purpose of visually estimating motion of a top-down drone mounted camera).
My current understanding (though I expect to be corrected on this) is that the algorithm should calculate the matrix centroid, obtain matrix of vectors shifted by that centroid, calculate eigenvectors from the covariance matrix, and then isolate rotation angle from the eigenvectors.
The catch is that I need to completely disregard "faulty" points with too little perceived motion (for example, vector length being less than e.g. the 80th percentile of all vectors), which makes my input matrix sparse with [NAN, NAN] vectors where the condition is not met. This makes me wonder if the covariance -> eigenvectors approach is going to give erroneous results for me.
Is there a well known algorithm to do this task? Should I just manually calculate the covariance matrix disregarding the NAN points? I'm honestly out of my depth here.
(Ideally, I would also like to be able to specify a non-central base point for the calculation but I guess that can be achieved by expanding the matrix with NAN values to make the desired point central.)
I would really appreciate guidance on this. Thanks!
For reference, this is the code I currently have for the dense matrix case:
centroid = np.mean(matrix, axis=(0, 1))
translated_points = matrix - centroid

# Reshape to treat each vector as a single point
flattened_points = np.reshape(translated_points, (-1, 2))

# Calculate the covariance matrix
covariance_matrix = np.cov(flattened_points, rowvar=False)

# Compute the eigenvectors and eigenvalues
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(covariance_matrix)

# Determine the rotation angle
rotation_angle = np.arctan2(eigenvectors[1, 0], eigenvectors[0, 0])

# Determine the translation vector
rotation_matrix = np.array([[np.cos(rotation_angle), -np.sin(rotation_angle)],
                             [np.sin(rotation_angle), np.cos(rotation_angle)]])
translation_vector = centroid - np.dot(rotation_matrix, centroid)
```


There is an abundant litterature on the Web about numerical treatment of optical flows. Have you explored it ?

I'm reading up what I can find of course but I wasn't able to find anything describing my problem. I would be grateful if you could point me to relevant source. Thanks!
